# Router doesn't display the content VueJS

Tags: javascript, java, html, vue.js

I'm wokring in vuejs and by some reason it doesn't display the content when its switching to another route. I have the following code:
in App.vue ->

```
<template>
 <div>
 <router-view> </router-view>
 </div>
</template>
```

in my routes.js ->

```
import Support from './components/support/Support.vue';
import Detailed from './components/support/details/Detailed.vue';

 export const routes =[

 {path: '/support', component: Support, children: [
   {path: 'detailed', component: Detailed, name: 'detailed'}
]},
];
```

in my Support.vue i have a component ->

```
    <div class="row">

 <component :is = "selectedComponent">   </component>

        </div>
```

and that component when selected displays certain content. Inside of this content i have -->

```
     <div class="most-asked">
    <ul>
         <router-link :to ="{name: 'detailed'}" tag = 'li'> Test    </router-link>

    </ul>
```

When i press on that  it changes the url in my browser to => "/support/detailed" but it doesnt redirect me to that page.
Any ideas on why it happens and how to fix it?

P.S if i make routes seperate in routes.js like -> /detailed and /support then it redirects me perfectly fine, but once i make a child of support, it doesnt go there anymore

P.S.S and by some reason it tells me sometimes in my browser that its unable to load files like 
(`Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8080/support/src/vendors/css/grid.css Failed to  the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

and `http://localhost:8080/support/src/vendors/css/ionicons.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I'm assuming if i include bootstrap and etc, its also not going to find it in those routes (why?), but if put all those routes seperatly without any children they work fine.

Comment: change the path to '/detailed' in the child routes

Comment: i tried it before. In browser url it changes to /detailed but stays on the same page of /support

Answer (score 1):

As i understand the reason it doesnt display it because it requires another `<router-view>  </router-view>` apart from the root one. So forwarding question would be, is what kind of logic can you create that will switch you between the pages?